# Is it possible to do code folding like feature but for reST/sphinx documents in emacs

Tags: code-folding, outline-mode, outline, rst-mode

I am switching from org-mode to writing docs/notes etc. in restructured text. I was wondering if in emacs we can achieve section/subsection level code folding. An outline-mode in a separate buffer would be even  work.